# How to send message notification to the connected device?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, core-bluetooth

I am making a bluetooth chat application, I want that when both devices are connected and one device sends a message to other then a notification comes that some device sent a message.

Please help me I am in trouble to solve this problem for a week.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1):

> By default, many of the common Core Bluetooth tasks—on both the central and peripheral side—are disabled while your app is in the background or in a suspended state. That said, you can declare your app to support the Core Bluetooth background execution modes to allow your app to be woken up from a suspended state to process certain Bluetooth-related events. Even if your app doesn’t need the full range of background processing support, it can still ask to be alerted by the system when important events occur.

Such events may be posted messages. As soon as the receiving app is woken up by the system, you can schedule a `UILocalNotification` for delivery.